# Remove a custom object from an array (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, cocoa-touch

I have an array called `remindersArray` that contains a custom object called `Reminder` (each `Reminder` object has `title` and `identifier`).

Inside `Reminder` I have a static fun called `removeReminderWithIdentifier` that should find the reminder and delete it from the array.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
static func removeReminderWithIdentifier(reminderIdentifier: String) {
    for currentReminder in Reminder.remindersArray {
        if currentReminder.identifier == reminderIdentifier {
            Reminder.remindersArray.removeAtIndex(Reminder.remindersArray.indexOf(currentReminder)) //Compile error
        }
    }
}
```

but it gives me this compile error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Reminder' to expected argument type '@noescape (Reminder) throws -> Bool'
```

Any idea how can I remove that object with this identifier from the array?

Thanks!

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the header of two `indexOf(_:)` methods for `CollectionType`:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
    /// Returns the first index where `value` appears in `self` or `nil` if
    /// `value` is not found.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(`self.count`).
    @warn_unused_result
    public func indexOf(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Self.Index?
}

extension CollectionType {
    /// Returns the first index where `predicate` returns `true` for the
    /// corresponding value, or `nil` if such value is not found.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(`self.count`).
    @warn_unused_result
    public func indexOf(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self.Index?
}
```

If you want to use the first `indexOf(_:)` (which you are trying in your code), the element type needs to be `Equatable`. When your `Reminder` class does not conform to `Equatable`, Swift ignores the first `indexOf(_:)`, so the second can be the only candidate, having `@noescape (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool` as its only argument. In your case `Self.Generator.Element` is `Reminder`.

So, one way to avoid this error is making your `Reminder` conform to `Equatable`.

```
extension Reminder: Equatable {}
func == (lhs: Reminder, rhs: Reminder) -> Bool {
    return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier /* && ... you may need more complex condition. */
    /* return lhs === rhs //or simple use `===`. */
}
```

But you have some options to do it:

If your `reminderArray` contains just one element for each unique `identifier`, you can write something like this, without making your `Reminder` `Equatable`:

```
static func removeReminderWithIdentifier(reminderIdentifier: String) {
    if let index = Reminder.remindersArray.indexOf({$0.identifier == reminderIdentifier}) {
        Reminder.remindersArray.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
}
```

If your `remindersArray` may contain multiple `Reminder` instances having the same `identifier`, this should work:

```
static func removeReminderWithIdentifier3(reminderIdentifier: String) {
    Reminder.remindersArray = Reminder.remindersArray.filter{$0.identifier != reminderIdentifier}
}
```

Choose one (or more?) and make it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter out the unwanted reminders:

```
static func removeReminderWithIdentifier(reminderIdentifier: String) {
    Reminder.remindersArray = Reminder.remindersArray.filter { $0.identifier != reminderIdentifier }
}
```

Alternately:

```
func removeReminderWithIdentifier(reminderIdentifier: String) {
    remindersArray = remindersArray.filter { $0.identifier != reminderIdentifier }
}
```

And in the latest swift naming style...:

```
func removeReminders(with identifier: String) {
    remindersArray = remindersArray.filter { $0.identifier != identifier }
}
```

Comment: `Cannot call value of non-function type '[Reminder]'`

Comment: Without seeing your code I am guessing...  Remove the `static` prefix and also the two references to `Reminder` in the func.  I've updated the answer accordingly.